# JSON array column into JSON object

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

Is it possible to turn a json array (`["a","b","c"]`) column into a json object (`{"a":"a", "b":"b", "c":"c"}`) in postgresql?

Answer (score 2):

Unnest the array with `jsonb_array_elements_text()` and aggregate the elements back using `jsonb_object_agg()`:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(value, value)
from jsonb_array_elements_text('["a","b","c"]'::jsonb);

        jsonb_object_agg        
--------------------------------
 {"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c"}
(1 row)
```